# Fatal error when installing gsutil on Mac, python 2.7.5

Tags: python, macos, compiler-errors, pip, gsutil

I need to install gsutil using pip for a project. I am trying to install it on a virtual environnement with Python 2.7.5 . To do so, I run the command:

```
pip install gsutil
```

At some point I get the error:

```
c/_cffi_backend.c:15:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory

#include <ffi.h>

             ^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I have no clue of how to solve this issue.

I've already looked on the internet, some people said to run:

```
sudo yum install python-dev
```

but this was not conclusive, as far as I understood this above command is used by developers, and I am not a developer.

Comment: `yum` is a Linux command (specifically Red Hat family distros); you need to find instructions for your specific platform. But the basic idea is correct; you are running a compiler (via `pip`) and it needs the required library to be installed.

Comment: How did you set up the virtual environment and `gcc`? Neither of these are standard on a Mac and there are many different ways to get them, each with different conventions and specifics.